# Can not run DAGs since upgraded from Airflow 1.7

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We installed Airflow 1.7, and used it for several months.  I used PIP to uninstall ariflow 1.7 and install 1.9 (gory details are [here|[airflow initdb failed: ImportError: No module named log.logging_mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544320/airflow-initdb-failed-importerror-no-module-named-log-logging-mixin).])

Since then, I haven't had a single DAG run.  I renamed and moved log files to match the 1.9 expectations, but still nothing happens.

I have a "run every 40 minutes" DAG, it hasn't run since 3/28.  When I manually trigger it, no log file is created, nothing happens except I get a running DAG listed under "DAG Runs" (I do NOT get anything listed under "Recent Tasks", and "Last Run" does not get updated.

I have a "Run once" DAG that I created.  I triggered it, same behavior.

I have also tried running the example_bash_operator DAG.  Same behavior.

Comment: Can you post the logs from the scheduler and the worker?

Comment: I assumed (word chosen w/ malice aforethought) that nohup airflow webserver -p 8080 would kick everything off.  I was wrong.  @tobi6 if you want to post your comment as an answer i'll give you the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Airflow documentation is a bit thin on all the requirements needed to run DAGs correctly.

Aside from the webserver, make sure the scheduler is running as well. Also check if the DAG is configured with a correct schedule and there is scheduling information in the "Task Instance Information" page.

See this answer for more "checkpoints": [Airflow 1.9.0 is queuing but not launching tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021055/airflow-1-9-0-is-queuing-but-not-launching-tasks/49047832#49047832)